# Windows 10 Explorer doesn't show Office file details

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2016

Windows Explorer shows details like author and title for old `.doc` files, but not for `.docx` or `.xlsx` files.

Right after I installed Office 2016, it would show them. But after I quit Word, it no longer does. In Word, I can see and edit .`docx`properties (title, author, etc.) but they aren't shown (just "Add a title" line) or editable in Explorer details panel. I tried to fix the Office, but nothing happened.